# Progress Dialogs with Sound in Android

Tags: java, android, audio, dialog, progress

I have searched around for possible answers, but did not find one that came close to what I require.

I am after creating a progress dialog in Android, the standard one with the spinning disk. However, what I want is for the dialog to play a looped sound sample as it spins which stops when its dismissed.

How would you go about doing this?

All the best

Andrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first `show()` your `ProgressDialog` start a looping `MediaPlayer`.

```
    MediaPlayer mAlarmPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alarm_1);
    mAlarmPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mAlarmPlayer.start();
```

when you will `dismiss()` your `ProgressDialog` just call:

```
    mAlarmPlayer.stop();
    mAlarmPlayer.release();
```

Comment: Thanks, I am giving this a go and actually seems a little more flexible than my anticipated solution which I believed was to extend the progress dialog or in some way encapsulate it in another class. If this works out I'll mark the answer as the accepted one.